# Reading Hi and Lo into two temporary registers

Tags: assembly, registry, mips, swap

im trying to make a macro that stores the values of HI and LO into two temp registers then swap them but im wondering how to go about storing them do i use mfhi and mflo to save them? if so how would i go about swapping them?

```
.macro print_str($arg)
        li $v0, 4 #System call code for print_str
        la $a0, $arg #Address of the string to print
        syscall     # print the string
        .end_macro

#macro : print_int
#usage : rint_int(<val>)                
.macro print_int($arg)
        li $v0, 1   # system call code for print_int
        li $a0, $arg   # integer to print
        syscall     # print the integer
        .end_macro 

.macro read_int($reg)
    li $v0, 5 #system call code to read_int
    syscall
    move $reg, $v0
    .end_macro


.macro print_reg_int($reg)
    li $v0, 1
    move $a0, $reg
    syscall
    .end_macro

.macro swap_hi_lo($temp1, $temp2)
    mtlo $a0
    mflo $temp1
    mthi $a0
    mfhi $temp2




.macro print_hi_lo($strHi, $strEqual, $strComma, $strLo)
       li $v0, 4
       la $a0, $strHi  #Address of the string to print
       syscall
       li $v0, 4
       la $a0, $strEqual    #Address of the string to print
       syscall
       li $v0, 4
       la $a0, $strComma #Address of the string to print
       syscall


 .macro exit
    li  $v0, 10 
    syscall
    .end_macro
```

Comment: Which assembler do you use?

Comment: Why would you need to swap them? Just pick the appropriate target registers for `mflo` and `mfhi`.

Comment: ya thats what im having trouble with im having a hard time figuring out the right registers ive posted what i have right now am i on the right track? @Michael

Answer (score 0):

Considering you're most likely in the same CS class I am taking. I figure I could help you out a bit with this tid bit of code. Read the comments! Explanation below code.

```
.macro swap_hi_lo($temp1, $temp2)
mfhi $temp1 #Set address of $temp1 to address of value stored in Hi
mflo $temp2 #Set address of $temp2 to address of value stored in Lo
move $t2, $temp1 #Move $temp1 to a temporary address for manipulation
move $t3, $temp2 #Move $temp2 to a temporary address for manipulation
mthi $t3 #Swap value of Hi with our Lo value
mtlo $t2 #Swap value of Lo value with our Hi value

syscall
.end_macro
```

Explanation:

- We set the value of $temp1 and $temp2 to the values of our hi and lo values because the arguments provided in the test file themselves are null temporary values (as I had to learn the hard way after an hour)
- Next we move our values from $temp1 and $temp2 to two temporary variables so we can swap the two values without any weird overlap happening.
- Lastly we assign our HI and LO values with the corresponding temporary value.

Another hint:

Use mfhi and mflo when you're printing the values of HI and LO for the second macro. If you need anymore help please feel free to ask!